# Html Page not Scrolling Down? CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

```js
      $(window).load(function() {
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
        $(".swipe-area").swipe({
          swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
            if (phase == "move" && direction == "left") {
              $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
              return false;
            }
            if (phase == "move" && direction == "right") {
              $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

```css
#headerMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #212021;
}
#logo a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #212021;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 10px;
}
#page-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
}
#headerMenu img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #212021;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 70%;
}
#menu img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #212021;
  top: -2px;
  left: 85%;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.container.open-sidebar {
  left: 240px;
}
.swipe-area {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 0;
}
#sidebar {
  background: #212021;
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -240px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  margin: 0;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212021;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar ul li:hover a {
  background: #212021;
}
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.main-content .content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-content .content h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
}
.main-content .content p {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 160%;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle {
  background: #212021;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 7px;
  float: left;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 300px) {
  #logo a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oxygen", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    background-color: #212021;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #headerMenu img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #212021;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 65%;
  }
  #menu img {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #212021;
    top: -2px;
    left: 80%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 200px) {
  #logo a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oxygen", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    background-color: #212021;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  #headerMenu img {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #212021;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 60%;
  }
  #menu img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #212021;
    top: -2px;
    left: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world</p>
```

I am making a website to learn css, html, and javascript. It was looking really good and it worked fine, and then I added the side menu and it wouldn't allow me to scroll down the page. Here is the Code:

I think it is the ' overflow: hidden; ' part of this section of code:

```
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
```

But I need ' overflow: hidden; ' to make the side bar open without the width of the getting page bigger, How would I apply it to just the side menu and not the main text? I have been trying to figure it out for hours and i still can't find out how to do it.

Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `overflow: hidden` causes this problem. Instead use

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

to **disable only** the **horizontal** scrolling.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/3aszc8te/)

---

You have the ability to control both, the vertical and horizontal scrolling, using the `x` and `y` axis.

```
.......|.......
.......y.......
.......|.......
–––––––––––x–––
.......|.......
.......|.......
.......|.......
```

You can target both individually using `overflow-x`, and `overflow-y`, or both at the same time using `overflow`. The values you can set are:

> auto;
>
> scroll;
>
> visible;
>
> hidden;
>
> initial;
>
> inherit;
>
> no-display;
>
> no-content;

[**Read more about it at w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: It will let me in 1 minute :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your CSS code:

```
 body, html {
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     font-family: helvetica;
     font-weight: 100;
 }
```

to this:

```
 body, html {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: helvetica;
     font-weight: 100;
 }
```

Basically using `overflow: hidden;` on your `<body>` tag, you were telling the web browser to hide any content that is beyond the user's screen, which removes the need to have scroll-bars.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nurnh1xc/)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the

```css
overflow : hidden;
```

this thing causes your page to scroll down 
if you don't want to show your page scroll down then only you need to add this CSS property to the body tag